# In Office JS/Word add-in - Is it possible to start other ribbon items/add-ins or the dictate API from a taskpane add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm using the Office JS for Word, and I would like to know if it is possible to start/open the Dictate add-in (or any other add-in/ribbon item) from within my own add-in.

After consulting the Office JS API, I was unable to find any leads if that is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office JavaScript API (OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for that.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.